# Installing Angular 4 in a ASP.NET Core 1.1 project?

Tags: asp.net, angular, installation

This should be basic but I have problems to find a guide on how to install Angular 4 into a ASP.NET Core 1.1 project?

I have found a couple of videos on youtube but they are all about Angular 2? The nuget packages goes to version 1.

I have followed this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g13I7Xy1PtI that installes Angular 4 on to the computer(nodejs and Angular CLI). This will also create a project but its not a ASP.NET Core project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Angular 2 first and then upgrade to Angular 4.